# regex to match only .gov tlds

Tags: regex, url

I am trying to write a regex to grab an entire url of any .gov or .edu web address to make it into a link.

I currently have:

`/(\b(https?|ftp):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/`

all in `()` so i can regurgitate it for *any url*, but I only want .gov or .edu ones.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*` appears to be slurping up most of the url, so we need to jam the .gov and .edu in here somewhere. The quickest solution would be:

`[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]+(\.gov|\.edu)[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*`

However, this will match a url like: `http://www.example.com/evil.gov/test.html`

To fix this, we can take out the `/` that it is matching before the top level domain:

`[-A-Z0-9+&@#%?=~_|!:,.;]+(\.gov|\.edu)[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*`

Or, in closing, we have:

`/(\b(https?|ftp):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#%?=~_|!:,.;]+(\.gov|\.edu)[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]?)/`

Due to the problem that it doesn't match example.gov, I added a `?` to the last token.

Damn that is ugly.

Comment: Note - many of those symbols are illegal in domain names.  Removing them would make it significantly less ugly.

Comment: thanks guys..and yes i will be removing some of that. i had it in there for testing.

Comment: Haha, I guess we could make it uglier, Pumbaa80.